# Issue on Getting Selected Row Values From Table with Checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/82uhe98b/3/)**

Can you please take a look at above demo and let me know why I am not able to get the values of selected (checked) rows from the table? I have a code like this:

```
$("#btn").on("click", function () {
    var checkedRows = [];
    $("#tbody tr").each(function () {

        if ($(this).find("input").is(":checked")) {
            checkedRows.push($(this).find("td:eq(1)").html());
        }
        // console.log(checkedRows);    
    });

        var result = [];

    $.each($("td:eq()"), function (idx, item) {
        if (checkedRows.indexOf(idx> -1)){ result.push(item);}
    });

    if (result.length < 2) {
        alert("Please Select 2 to 4 Models");
    }
    if (result.length > 4) {
        alert("Please Select 2 to 4 Models");
    } else {
        console.log(result);
    }
    });
```

and HTML as:

```
<table border="1" width="100%">
        <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type='checkbox' /></td>
                        <td>Row 1, cell 2</td>
                        <td>Row 2, cell 3</td>
                </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
                <tr>
                        <td><input type='checkbox' /></td>
                        <td>Row 2, cell 2</td>
                        <td>Row 2, cell 3</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                        <td><input type='checkbox' /></td>
                        <td>Row 3, cell 2</td>
                        <td>Row 3, cell 3</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                        <td><input type='checkbox' /></td>
                        <td>Row 4, cell 2</td>
                        <td>Row 4, cell 3</td>
                     <tr>
                        <td><input type='checkbox' /></td>
                        <td>Row 4, cell 2</td>
                        <td>Row 4, cell 3</td>
                </tr>
                </tr>
        </tbody>
</table>
<input id="btn" type="button" label="button" value="get rows" />
```

Thanks,

> **Update**

```
result = [
           [' Row 1, cell 2 ' , ' Row 2, cell 3 '],
           [' Row 2, cell 2 ' , ' Row 2, cell 3 '],
           [' Row 1, cell 2 ' , ' Row 2, cell 3 ']
        ]
```

Comment: What's your goal here `$.each($("td:eq()"), function (idx, item) {
        if (checkedRows.indexOf(idx> -1)){ result.push(item);}
    });`?

Comment: To be honest I got lost. Technicality what I want to do is generating Array of each selected row and pushing them in result arry

Comment: Which is done using the first `.each()` ... then what?

Comment: But I am not getting any result back at the end!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Getting the second column html of all the checked rows is quite straight forward; `.map()` makes it really easy:

```
    $('#btn').on('click', function() {
        var checkedRows = $(':checkbox:checked')
        .closest('tr').find('td:eq(1)').map(function() { 
            return $(this).html(); 
         }).get();
         console.log( checkedRows );
    });
```

```js
    $('#btn').on('click', function() {
        var checkedRows = $(':checkbox:checked')
        .closest('tr').find('td:eq(1)').map(function() { 
            return $(this).html(); 
         }).get();
        
        //Output --- just for demo
        $('pre.out').text( JSON.stringify( checkedRows ) );
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1" width="100%">
        <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type='checkbox' /></td>
                        <td>Row 1, cell 2</td>
                        <td>Row 2, cell 3</td>
                </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
                <tr>
                        <td><input type='checkbox' /></td>
                        <td>Row 2, cell 2</td>
                        <td>Row 2, cell 3</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                        <td><input type='checkbox' /></td>
                        <td>Row 3, cell 2</td>
                        <td>Row 3, cell 3</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                        <td><input type='checkbox' /></td>
                        <td>Row 4, cell 2</td>
                        <td>Row 4, cell 3</td>
                     <tr>
                        <td><input type='checkbox' /></td>
                        <td>Row 4, cell 2</td>
                        <td>Row 4, cell 3</td>
                </tr>
                </tr>
        </tbody>
</table>
<input id="btn" type="button" label="button" value="get rows" />

<pre class="out"></pre>
```

**UPDATE**

To generate an array of array as indicated in the your comments under this question, here is the code:

```
$('#btn').on('click', function() {
    var checkedRows = [];
    $(':checkbox:checked').closest('tr').each(function() {
        checkedRows.push(
          $(this).find('td:gt(0)').map(function() {
              return $(this).html();
          }).get()
        ); 
     });

    console.log( checkedRows );
});
```

```js
    $('#btn').on('click', function() {
        var checkedRows = [];
        $(':checkbox:checked').closest('tr').each(function() {
            checkedRows.push(
              $(this).find('td:gt(0)').map(function() {
                  return $(this).html();
              }).get()
            ); 
         });
        
        //Output --- just for demo
        $('pre.out').text( JSON.stringify( checkedRows ) );
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1" width="100%">
        <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type='checkbox' /></td>
                        <td>Row 1, cell 2</td>
                        <td>Row 2, cell 3</td>
                </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
                <tr>
                        <td><input type='checkbox' /></td>
                        <td>Row 2, cell 2</td>
                        <td>Row 2, cell 3</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                        <td><input type='checkbox' /></td>
                        <td>Row 3, cell 2</td>
                        <td>Row 3, cell 3</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                        <td><input type='checkbox' /></td>
                        <td>Row 4, cell 2</td>
                        <td>Row 4, cell 3</td>
                     <tr>
                        <td><input type='checkbox' /></td>
                        <td>Row 4, cell 2</td>
                        <td>Row 4, cell 3</td>
                </tr>
                </tr>
        </tbody>
</table>
<input id="btn" type="button" label="button" value="get rows" />

<pre class="out"></pre>
```

**OUTPUT:** -- with all checkboxes selected.

```
[
    ["Row 1, cell 2","Row 2, cell 3"],
    ["Row 2, cell 2","Row 2, cell 3"],
    ["Row 3, cell 2","Row 3, cell 3"],
    ["Row 4, cell 2","Row 4, cell 3"],
    ["Row 4, cell 2","Row 4, cell 3"]
]
```

Comment: Hi Peter and thanks for what you have done but what I need is loading selected values in an array of array like `result = [
              [' Row 1, cell 2 ' , ' Row 2, cell 3 '],
              [' Row 2, cell 2 ' , ' Row 2, cell 3 '],
             .....
              [' Row 1, cell 2 ' , ' Row 2, cell 3 '],
          ]`

Comment: Can you please let me know how to do that?

Comment: I am sorry it seems like I cant explain what I need! can you please take a look at update?

Comment: What I need to get at end is a  array like hard coded array at the update

Comment: And how does that differ from the output from my updated demo?

Comment: No problem. Glad I could be of help.

Comment: @PeterKA I have each `tr` with 5 `td`s and with your code only last 3 `td`s are added to array. What might be the reason?

Comment: Please provide sample row HTML.

Answer (score 1):

`$("#tbody tr")` should be `$("tbody tr")` because `tbody` is not an ID. Also suggest you to add `input type` in if condition (`input[type=checkbox]`).

```
$("#btn").on("click", function () {
    var checkedRows = [];
    $("tbody tr").each(function () {
        if ($(this).find("input[type=checkbox]").is(":checked")) {
            checkedRows.push($(this).find("td:eq(1)").html());
        }
    });
    console.log(checkedRows);
    //......
});
```